# Pass checkbox list multiple selected value to stored procedure through one parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, checkboxlist, multivalue, multipleselection

i have checkbox list to select multiple value  ,now i want to pass this multiple selected value to my stored procedure using one parameter

```
insert into tblAccessRights (roleid,customerid,SubcustomerId)
values(@_roleid,@CustomerId,@SubcustomerId,)
```

in above query @SubcustomerId is parameter which will hold the multiple selected value from checkboxlist
so,now the entry should be like as follow

```
roleid customerid subcustomerid
 1        2           6
 1        2           7
 1        2           8
```

this subcustomerid is multiple selected value from check box ,how can i achieve this with one parameter,if any other way to do this then please reply

Can it be done with dynamic query if i take checkboxlist value as comma separated string and accordingly pass it to dynamic insert query...

Comment: i got solution for this finally,!!!! im giving my solution for refrence

Comment: i took the check box list in string as comma separated value and pass it to stored procedure  then i use dynamic query to insert this value as follow:create table tblrmp
(
id int identity (1,1),
name varchar(20),
subcat varchar(20)

)

declare @S varchar(20)
set @S = '1,2,3,4,5'

declare @sql varchar(max)

while len(@S) > 0
begin
  print left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1)
  set @sql='insert into tblrmp values(''abc'','+left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1)+')'
 -- exec YourSP left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1)
 exec(@sql)
   set @S = stuff(@S, 1, charindex(',', @S+','), '')
end

Comment: output:id name subcat
1 abc 1
2 abc 2
3 abc 3
4 abc 4
5 abc 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution for this finally,!!!! im giving my solution for refrence

i took the check box list in string as comma separated value and pass it to stored procedure then i use dynamic query to insert this value as follow:

```
 
create table tblrmp
 ( id int identity (1,1),
 name varchar(20), 
subcat varchar(20) )
```

declare @S varchar(20) 
set @S = '1,2,3,4,5' 
declare @sql varchar(max)
 while len(@S) > 0
 begin
 print left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1) 
set @sql='insert into tblrmp values(''abc'','+left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1)+')'  exec(@sql) 
set @S = stuff(@S, 1, charindex(',', @S+','), '')
 end

output:
id  name    subcat
1   abc      1
2   abc      2 
3   abc      3 
4   abc      4 
5   abc      5